# Cannot emit Signal in PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

```
class MyPlotWidget(pg.PlotWidget):
    myplotSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.clickplotSignal = self.scene().sigMouseClicked
        self.clickplotSignal.connect(self.mouse_clicked)

    def mouse_clicked(self, mouseClickEvent):
        self.signal = id(self)
        plotDialog.plotIndex = plotDialog.id_list.index(self.signal)
        self.myplotSignal.emit(self.signal)

class MyGraph():
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def test(self,signal):
        print("signal accepted")

class another(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.plot = MyPlotWidget()
        self.graph = MyGraph()
        self.plot.myplotSignal.connect(self.graph.test)
```

I've been running functions by specifying signals and slots in this way for a long time,

but it doesn't seem to emit in `MyPlotWidget` class this time. Why? please help me :(((

I used `clickplotSignal` to connect slot directly, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try changing to `QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)`

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of making signal is valid. I believe that mouse_clicked method is not called that is why your signal never emits.

Comment: yes, in mouse_clicked() method, it works well without emit. like Print etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please go with run function override method.
hope that will work for you.

```
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        """Long-running task."""
        for i in range(5):
            sleep(1)
            self.progress.emit(i + 1)
        self.finished.emit()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).